# How to: Backing up a Ontology?

Tags: java, backup, ontology

I'm working on a dynamic system that uses a not too big ontology, to make correct decisions based on received information. I need to back up this ontology, together with its individuals so that the system can be restored after failure, but I don't know the ontology, nor how many individuals it contains, so the backing up needs to be as generic as possible.

I would prefer that one function could be called, just to signal my backing up part of the code can do its thing, instead of demanding from the ontology code to call a method for each seperate ontology or individual.

Using the OWL API, is this possible? Can I back up my system in a generic way?

Comment: When you say that you don't know the ontology, do you mean its structure as well?

Comment: How do you currently store the ontology? e.g. in memory(when the program starts running the classes are loaded or do you read some configuration from static files and then create the ontology based on this configuration?)

Comment: @Keyser Well, I need the back up service to be entirely independent from the ontology. So yeah that's basicly what i'm saying. 

Could I make the method: public void backup(OWLOntology ont){ ... } and then use the save/write to file methods from the OWL api to succesfuly back up? That way only one method has to be called by the service who wants to initiate the backup.

Comment: @aviad The ontology does not exist yet, I could make a dummy one to test my back up service, but it needs to be able to back up any ontology.

Comment: Can work. You need to decide in what format you will store your ontology (XML, JSON, etc), then for example the backup method can create an XML out of every semantic entity you can use JAXB/XStream/gson to achieve that (Java to XML/JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [Jena](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/) it supports persistent ontologies.
Also, you need to decide in what format you will store your ontology (XML, JSON, etc), then for example, the backup method can create an XML out of every semantic entity. You can use [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)/[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)/[gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to achieve that (Java to XML/JSON).
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks alot! Now when you mean "semantic entity" you mean every individual/axiom etc. ?   

So basicly, when my backup gets the OWLOntology object, it needs to unravel the ontology and then parse that to a structured format like xml/json so it's easier to restore it in the future?

Comment: Yes. You need to have a root of your ontology and under it different types. So, backup process will scan recursively from the root every single entity, then will create its XML/JSON representation and append to one big an XML/JSON file that will be used for the backup. Alternatively, use Jena API it has the described functionality out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks alot, I will try both and see wich of them will be easiest to manage when the entire system goes life.